# How to get the cutoff timestamp or lastrevid for a given Wikidata JSON dump?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata, wikimedia, wikidata-api, wikimedia-dumps

I am using Wikidata enriched with other data sources and I must ingest the entire [Wikidata JSON dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/) in a dev graph database of mine.

That's easy and once that's done, I want to keep my copy updated by querying the RecentChanges and LogEvents API endpoints to retrieve de changes/deletes/creates that occurred between two timestamps (I'd do so every few minutes) - and that's relatively easy too!

*What I cannot get my head around is...*

**How to get the cutoff timestamp for a given JSON dump?** Where is this available or how to figure it out since the `modified` timestamp and `lastrevid` fields aren't present in JSON dumps.

Comment: It looks like this is not currently possible.
Some of the dumps have structured data about them Example: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/20181020/dumpstatus.json
But not the JSON entities dump.
I have created the following task to track this: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T209390